# What are other wordings for pushing the following pedals?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

What verbs to use with clutch/brake/accelerator? I need verbs that mean pushing the pedal.

Do you say "push the brake/accelerator in"?

Do you say "hit/slam on the clutch/accelerator"?

Do you say "put the clutch/accelerator on"?

Thank you.

Comment: 'Step on' a pedal is common: the clutch/accelerator/brakes (plural).

Comment: We don't say 'push in' in this context. 'Hit' or 'slam on' would only be appropriate if the action was sudden and violent (such as an emergency stop). 'Put down' can be used.

Comment: 'Step on the gas' is common to mean 'go faster', and 'step on the brakes' for 'slow down or stop'. As Kate says, we 'slam on' the brakes in an emergency to stop quickly.

Comment: If you're being a bit more formal, you can "depress" a pedal or you can "depress the accelerator".